# I would like to know why question 16313526 was closed

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions, close-reasons

Leaving aside the content of the XML...

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313526/parsefromstring-cant-parse-string-properly) (10K needed to see) which received 5 downvotes and then the moderator deleted the question.

Why was it? Was it because of a problem from my side?

Comment: The swearing accounts for the downvotes.... Looks maybe like your post got offensive flagged. The contents of the XML cannot be ignored.

Comment: You claim for -10 votes, once I got +6/-2 and it was deleted. :p

Comment: Putting your answer aside, I'm surprised the mod didn't close the question first. At first glance, I don't see anything glaringly wrong with it.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: then only his answer should have been deleted not the question.

Comment: My answer was copied from the contents of the question

Comment: The question when it was posted had that content

Comment: **Ah...** [You're right...](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16313526/1) The edit ending up getting you framed...

Comment: if somebody had gone through the revision!!!

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards can you go to the revision of the question

Comment: I copied the content from the question and just added a wrapped element to it, didn't checked the content

Comment: Yeah, Ive just seen @arun. Above I was explaining _why_ I think it happened. As I say, you can't ignore the contents of the XML. You simply shouldn't have copied it if you didn't want this to happen...

Comment: Answer only after reading the whole question. Anyway the question was nuked and everything is gone.. Which is good

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I would say lesson learned in the hard way

Comment: Most of the time, when we are in the race to answer first... within minutes the question, code etc gets changed, and our answers looks ODD.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The original question contained some language that people objected to. Your answer mirrored that but was attracting more adverse attention than the now edited question.

The question itself wasn't worth saving, I think there might be the smell of a troll. The simplest course seemed to be to cut the losses by deleting the whole lot and starting with a blank slate.

Comment: thanks people, lesson learned and will be careful hereafter

Comment: Most likely the user got upset by his questions getting downvoted, closed and deleted so he started trolling. @Arun proper way of action would have been to edit the question first to take out the bad language and only then answer.

Comment: Yup, had your answer not received quite so many downvotes I'd have edited and cleared the flags but it was past the point where that made sense when I got to it.

Answer (score 14):

Looks like you're the victim of some absolutely horrible timing and sequence of events.

1. OP posts the question with profanity in the code.
2. You copy-paste the code and fix it. (I'm not sure if you noticed the profanity.)
3. The profanity gets edited out of the question. But stays in your answer.
4. Your answer gets downvoted for the profanity. (The downvoters probably never saw it came from the question first.)
5. Flexo sees flags on the question. Sees the revision history, and nukes the whole thing.