# Question deletions and undeletions are not showing in the timeline

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, timeline

Investigating [this question about a user who deletes his own questions improperly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178570/148310), I opened [the timeline for the example question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16312257/timeline).  But, as you can see, it doesn't show any deletions or undeletions!

[(Click for larger view)

[image: current timeline]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UjKp.gif)

---

According to [the kickoff post about the *Timeline View*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36303/148310), the timeline is supposed to include

> - initial question ask
> - answers
> - revisions
> - comments
> - closure, **deletion**, reopen, **undelete**, etc
> - votes

And, the question does show as deleted and undeleted in [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16312257/revisions):

[(Click for larger view)

[image: Question edit history]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epYHq.gif)

---

Unfortunately, the *question* revision-history is not as useful as the *question-and-answer* timeline, for things like this -- especially since terms like "1 hour ago", "2 hours ago", etc. are not precise enough when comparing two or more pages.

Please fix the timeline view to (once again) show when a question is deleted and/or undeleted.

Comment: I'm fine as long as the timeline doesn't start showing the relationship status of the question ;-)

Comment: @Manishearth, ¿Huh? ... Are you referring to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178588/148310), or what?

Comment: Not really, but now I _want_ to say that I was ;-)